# Magento shared user sessions works in all browsers EXCEPT Safari

Tags: magento, safari

Good day.

I have a multi-website/store Magento installation running 2 websites and would like to know how to get Magento's shared session/cart working between different websites of the same store in Safari.

**Brief on How Magento Handles Sessions**

When switching from one cart-shared website to another, magento will tack on the SID (session ID) to the URL of the landing page. After navigating from that page, the session should still be remembered, but removed from the address bar as it is no longer needed.

Shared Session URL Example
Transferring from www.website1.com will result in a www.website2.com/?SID=[encrypted key] kind of URL for the landing page only.

**The Problem**

Upon switching from www.website1.com to www.website2.com, the session ID is lost in Safari. In other words, the SID appears on the landing page's address bar, but the session isn't actually loaded/saved. No items are in the cart and the user is logged out if they were logged in on website1.

Safari version is 5.2.1, on Windows 7. Mobile Android phone does the exact thing as Safari, running Dolphin 9.3.2.

Session transferring is working perfectly in the latest browsers as of April 2013: Chrome, IE, and FireFox browsers on Windows 7.

If I add the SID into the address bar manually and refresh, I get the session.

**Solutions Researched So Far**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17924/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/36473/

(can't post more links, but I've also read through thread 60749)

**Solutions Tried So Far with No Effect**

- Turned off Persistent Cart (undone after testing)
- Removed duplicate emails addresses from database
- Set “Share Customer Accounts” to Global
- Set “Cookie Domain” to either [website1].com or [website2].com (undone after testing)
- Turned off ‘Use Secure URLs in Frontend’ (undone after testing)
- Turned off “HTTP Only” for cookies (undone after testing)
- Turned off OneStepCheckout, cart still doesn’t transfer in Safari only (undone after testing)
- Set Unsecure url to “https” (undone after testing)
- Cleared cache and session files
- Cleared Magento and system cache
- Restarted Apache
- Re-synced server time
- Turned on “Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT” (undone after testing)
- Forcefully setting the session ID to whatever passed from [website1], resulted in an error (undone after testing)
- Tested while logged in and logged out, same bug result. Logged in user is logged out

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: You're probably more likely to get an answer [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to your problem, i am having the same problem?

Comment: Sadly, no. We basically resorted to passing the email & encrypted password from websiteA to websiteB in order to work around this. it's a poor workaround really, but there's not much option.